# How to calculate time difference in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have created a table with columns of datatype `time(7)`

I want to calculate the time difference between them.

Table `time`:

```
 id   timefrom     timeto      result
 --------------------------------------
 1    13:50:00     14:10:00    00:20:00   
 2    11:10:00     11:00:00    23:50:00
```

For example:

- Time From   13:50
- Time To     14:10

Result should show **00:20**.

Is there a function for this?

```
DATEDIFF(hour, UseTimeFrom, UseTimeTo) hourtime,
(DATEDIFF(MINUTE, UseTimeFrom , UseTimeTo)) - (((DATEDIFF(hour, UseTimeFrom, UseTimeTo)) * 60)) as mintime
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
select *, convert(time, convert(datetime, timeto) - convert(datetime, timefrom)) 
from table1
```

This will convert the times to datetime for day 0 (1.1.1900) and then do the calculation and in case the timeto is smaller it will get to previous day, but convert to time will get the time part from it.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e56fc/1)

Answer (score 1):

There's no built-in function - but you could relatively easily write your own T-SQL stored function to calculate this - something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.TimeDifference (@FromTime TIME(7), @ToTime TIME(7))
RETURNS VARCHAR(10)
AS BEGIN
    DECLARE @Diff INT = DATEDIFF(SECOND, @FromTime, @ToTime)

    DECLARE @DiffHours INT = @Diff / 3600;
    DECLARE @DiffMinutes INT = (@Diff % 3600) / 60;
    DECLARE @DiffSeconds INT = ((@Diff % 3600) % 60);

    DECLARE @ResultString VARCHAR(10)

    SET @ResultString = RIGHT('00' + CAST(@DiffHours AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
                        RIGHT('00' + CAST(@DiffMinutes AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + ':' +
                        RIGHT('00' + CAST(@DiffSeconds AS VARCHAR(2)), 2)

    RETURN @ResultString
END
```

This function uses the integer division (`/`) and integer remainder (`%`) operators to calculate the number of hours, minutes and seconds that those two times are apart, and then concatenates those together into a string as you are looking for.

```
SELECT 
    dbo.TimeDifference('13:50:00', '14:10:00'),
    dbo.TimeDifference('13:50:00', '15:51:05'),
    dbo.TimeDifference('13:50:00', '15:35:45')
```

Sample output:

```
00:20:00     02:01:05     01:45:45
```